# FTP giving less uploading speed compare to SCP

Tags: ftp, scp, upload

If I upload file using SCP then I get uploading speed up to 1.5 MB/s

```
scp filename  root@SERVER_IP:/path/to/store/
```

and If I use FTP to upload same file on same server then I get uploading speed up to 220 kB/s

```
ncftpput -R -v -u FTP_USER -p FTP_PWD SERVER_IP /path/ file.tgz
```

What could be the reason behind this degradation ?

Comment: Try to use FTP to another server. First with one on the local network. Do the speeds also differ if you do that? Do the speeds differ when you try another remote machine. Basically try some more testing first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of network you're working in, but if it's an external network, your ISP or hosting provider could have bandwidth throttling in place for FTP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling

Comment: Ok..if this is the problem ..then should I talk to my service provider ?

Comment: You could ask them for confirmation, sure. Unfortunately, if that is the case, there is not much you can do. You could try changing the port of your FTP server and hope that it'll spoof the throttling system, but most likely that won't be any help at all.

Comment: How can I be sure that this is the problem behind degradation ?

Answer (score 0):

If ftp is being throttled by your ISP, try using it over a different port. That's what I did and I used ports 81 or 444.

Let us know the result.

Comment: I changed the port but still getting same speed.

Comment: Try to download something via http (using wget or similar) and see what the speed is for that one.

Comment: I tried this..and I am getting speed more than 1MB/s.

Comment: The pattern is clear, assuming you have repeated and verified these results, you can conclude that scp and http operate at a much higher speed than ftp.